# Writing list to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(open(file, 'rU'), 'fasta', generic_protein):
    record_id = re.sub(r'\d+_(\d+_\d\#\d+)_\d+', r'\1', record.id)

    if ( not reference_sequence ):
      reference_sequence = record.seq
      reference_name     = record_id
      #continue
    print ",".join([reference_name, record_id, compare_seqs(reference_sequence, record.seq)])
```

gives terminal output that looks like

```
7065_8#1,8987_2#53,
7065_8#1,8987_2#58,
7065_8#1,8987_2#61,
7065_8#1,8987_2#62,E-G [246]
7065_8#1,8987_2#65,N-K [71],Y-D [223]
```

I want to write this line by line to a CSV, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack all records in a nested list (i.e. instead of `print ','.join(...)` you do `records.append([...])`) and then you can use `writerows(records)` to write them to the file. No need to do something like `'.'.join()` that's what csv does for you.

For the sake of completeness:

```
records = []
for record in SeqIO.parse(open(file, 'rU'), 'fasta', generic_protein):
    record_id = re.sub(r'\d+_(\d+_\d\#\d+)_\d+', r'\1', record.id)

    if ( not reference_sequence ):
      reference_sequence = record.seq
      reference_name     = record_id
      #continue
    records.append([reference_name, record_id, compare_seqs(reference_sequence, record.seq)])

with csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w')) as fp:
    fp.writerows(records)  # note that it's not writerow but writerows which allows you to write muptiple rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can suse `writerow` to save your outputs with following :

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(open(file, 'rU'), 'fasta', generic_protein):
    record_id = re.sub(r'\d+_(\d+_\d\#\d+)_\d+', r'\1', record.id)

if ( not reference_sequence ):
  reference_sequence = record.seq
  reference_name     = record_id
  #continue
line= ",".join([reference_name, record_id, compare_seqs(reference_sequence, record.seq)])
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([line])
```

Comment: you're welcome ! now you can tell this to community with accepting the answer !

Comment: I would like to point out that if you use `csv` there is no necessity of using `','.join` here cause that's exactly what `csv` does for you.

Comment: im not sure because in python doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents after reading rows from `csv` use `','.join` for pritnt !!!

Comment: `csv` dont save datas with `,` but you can print data with `,`

Comment: Because in the example from your link `csv.reader` is used and what you get from it is a nested list. So to display it you have to use `join`. But using `csv.writer` you should do it the other way round and write a nested list to the file. Like you did it it also becomes a bit messy, you should just use the python built-in `output.write` then you don't have to specify the lineterminator, etc. Ahm and to your second comment: yes, `csv` does. Try `csv.writer.writerows([[1,2],[3,4]])`. The output will be two lines and the elements in each line separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write the comma separated string (along with quotechar) directly to the file:

```
f = open("output.csv","w")
for record in SeqIO.parse(open(file, 'rU'), 'fasta', generic_protein):
  record_id = re.sub(r'\d+_(\d+_\d\#\d+)_\d+', r'\1', record.id)

  if ( not reference_sequence ):
    reference_sequence = record.seq
    reference_name     = record_id
    #continue
  csvrow =  '","'.join([reference_name, record_id, compare_seqs(reference_sequence, record.seq)])
  csvrow = '"'+csvrow+'"'
  print >>f, csvrow
f.close()
```

Using this method, you can open the file and check if the data is being written, even when the script is running.